# Stop SelectionChanged Event on Datagrid triggered by selection changing on row details sub grid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a master WPF datagrid which contains a details "sub" datagrid with selectionchanged trigegrs on both grids

```
<DataGrid x:Name="RepertoiresDataGrid"
            SelectionChanged="RepertoiresDataGrid_SelectionChanged">
..
..
  <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <DataGrid x:Name="CommentsDataGrid"  
                  CanUserAddRows="True"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                  CanUserSortColumns="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Comments}"
                  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                  SelectionChanged="CommentsDataGrid_SelectionChanged">
      .. 
      ..
```

In backing code

```
    private void CommentsDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, 
                                        SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void RepertoiresDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, 
                                         SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CommentsAsync(sender);
    }
```

The RepertoiresDataGrid_SelectionChanged works as expected in that it triggers when the selection is change in the RepertoiresDataGrid

The CommentsDataGrid_SelectionChanged works almost as expected in that it triggers whene the selection is changed in CommentsDataGrid but after this is triggered the RepertoiresDataGrid_SelectionChanged is also triggered.

Is it possible to stop the event chain after dealing with the CommentsDataGrid_SelectionChanged call?

Answer (score 0):

Add e.Handled = true; to the

```
private void CommentsDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, 
                                    SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

This will stop the event chain.